# Pandas DataFrame: select row-wise max value in absolute terms

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with only numeric data:

```
[ In1]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3).round(2), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
        df

[Out1]:         A       B       C
        0   -0.27    1.22    1.10
        1   -3.22    0.48   -1.64
        2    1.42    0.24   -0.12
        3   -1.12    0.44    0.23
        4    1.88   -0.38    0.62
```

How do I select, for each row, the max value in absolute terms while preserving the sign?

In this case it would be:

```
0     1.22
1    -3.22
2     1.42
3    -1.12
4     1.88
```

I got as far as determining which column to use:

```
[ In2]: loc_max = df.abs().idxmax(axis=1)
        loc_max

[Out2]: 
        0    B
        1    A
        2    A
        3    A
        4    A
```

Performance is important because my actual dataframe is big.

---

**SOLUTIONS COMPARISON:**

All answers below will give the desired outcome.

Performance comparison on a slightly bigger dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 100).round(2))

def numpy_argmax():
    idx_max = np.abs(df.values).argmax(axis=1)
    val = df.values[range(len(df)), idx_max]
    return pd.Series(val, index=df.index)

def check_sign():
    row_max = df.abs().max(axis=1)
    return row_max * (-1) ** df.ne(row_max, axis=0).all(axis=1)

def loop_rows():
    return df.apply(lambda s: s[s.abs().idxmax()], axis=1)

def pandas_loc():
    s = df.abs().idxmax(axis=1)
    val = [df.loc[x, y] for x, y in zip(s.index, s)]
    return pd.Series(val, index=df.index)

%timeit numpy_argmax()
%timeit check_sign()
%timeit loop_rows()
%timeit pandas_loc()
```

Results:

[image]

As usual going to the `numpy` level behind `pandas` curtain achieves the best performance. (Let me know if that's not always true.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us use `argmax` on the absolute values to find the indices of the maximum absolute values. Then use these indices to get the corresponding values from each row.

```
v = df.values
v[range(len(v)), np.abs(v).argmax(axis=1)]
```

---

```
array([ 1.22, -3.22,  1.42, -1.12,  1.88])
```

Comment: This is the fastest method. To be precise I also need to preserve the original index of the dataframe (it's not numeric but date-id multi-indexed in my real data).

Comment: @data-monkey we can assign the result back to a new dataframe column to preserve the index.

Comment: yes which is what I did in my SOLUTIONS COMPARISON in the edited OP.

Comment: Its nice to see the quantitative performance results...good job.

Answer (score 1):

A method that builds on your attempt, using numpy indices and numpy broadcasting rules:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3).round(2), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
idx_max = np.argmax( df.abs(), axis=1)
df.values[range(len(df)), idx_max]
```

Comment: Your answer is identical to @Shubham Sharma. I had to accept his because he posted slightly ahead of you.

Comment: @data-monkey Makes sense, I genuinely did not see his answer before posting mine.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
s = df.abs().idxmax(axis=1)
[df.loc[x, y] for x, y in zip(s.index, s)]
```